# line_to, fill_rect, and clear_rect functions

Tags: ruby, graphics, coordinate-system, overloading

```
def line_to(x: 0, y: 0, rect: nil)
  unless rect.nil?
    x, y, width, height = rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
  end

  `#{@context}.lineTo(#{x}, #{y})`
end

def fill_rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, rect: nil)
  unless rect.nil?
    x, y, width, height = rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
  end

  `#{@context}.fillRect(#{x}, #{y}, #{width}, #{height})`
end

def clear_rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, rect: nil)
  unless rect.nil?
    x, y, width, height = rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
  end

  `#{@context}.clearRect(#{x}, #{y}, #{width}, #{height})`
end
```

I am looking for a way to refactor the above code to take out the first three lines in the methods. I don't want to use Metaprogramming in this specific case; is there any other way?

In case full code will help, see the [repo](https://github.com/JikkuJose/Conway-Game-of-Life/blob/776519576eaf28c85fbd87819ecd0de6535dd10f/app/conway/helpers.rb).

Comment: Do these functions appear in a class? If so, could you show us the whole class? Also, could you explain why there are backticks?

Comment: Yes they are in a class and its `Opal`, backticks are to evaluate `JS`. Have just updated the post with the link to the full code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you want to be able to call these methods with two different signatures:

```
method(x: .., y: .., height: .., width: ..)
method(rect: ..)
```

There has to be *some* logic in the methods to decide which signature to use. I like your current solution for that. Using metaprogramming would make things too complicated.

Since the signatures are different, you could argue they are actually two different methods: `#line_to` and `#line_to_rectangle` for example. You could simply define two different methods:

```
def line_to(x, y)
  `#{@context}.lineTo(#{x}, #{y})`
end

def line_to_rectangle(rectangle)
  line_to(rectangle.x, rectangle.y)
end
```

*The best solution would be to only expect a single signature in the first place.*

One way to do that is to use `**` to pass a rectangle object as keyword arguments. For this to work you have to define a `#to_hash`.

```
class Rectangle
  def to_hash
    { :x => self.x, :y => self.y, :width => self.width, :height => self.height }
  end
end

...

line_to(**rectangle)
```

You'll have to make sure that `#line_to` takes **all** keys returned by `Rectangle#to_hash`. That means it should also a `width` and `height` keyword argument. You can do this by taking them explicitly or implicitly (`def line_to(x: 0, y: 0, **discard)`). If you don't take those unnecessary arguments it will raise an exception. Hardly ideal.

Another way to do that would be to create a second type of object to replace the keyword arguments (`x`, `y`, `width` and `height`). It should have the same interface as rectangle. I'd recommend not complicating things this much, though, and pick a single signature.

Comment: Exactly! I am trying to do `method overloading`; I know it isn't there in Ruby. But still trying for a good way for this. I am thinking of using something like a lambda; but won't the variables die of when it quits! I can do an eval! But that to me is dirty.

Comment: I added some extra, non-ideal, solutions. I hope the main message is clear: pick a single method signature :P

Answer (score 0):

Does factoring out the common logic help?

```
def line_to(x: 0, y: 0, rect: nil)
  x, y, width, height = try_rect_values(x, y, width, height, rect)
  `#{@context}.lineTo(#{x}, #{y})`
end

def fill_rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, rect: nil)
  x, y, width, height = try_rect_values(x, y, width, height, rect)
  `#{@context}.fillRect(#{x}, #{y}, #{width}, #{height})`
end

def clear_rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, rect: nil)
  x, y, width, height = try_rect_values(x, y, width, height, rect)
  `#{@context}.clearRect(#{x}, #{y}, #{width}, #{height})`
end

def try_rect_values(x, y, width, height, rect)
  return x, y, width, height if rect.nil?

  return rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
end
```

Comment: Well, not something I am looking for, but thanks for your time. Anyways, I think you can avoid _width_ & _height_ if _rect_ is `nil`.